# Make button-click store API data in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How do I get a button-click, to store data retrieved from API into localStorage?

The result from following is somewhat what I want to get stored:

```
function getResults(query) {
    fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=XXXXXX`)
        .then(weather => {
            return weather.json()
        })
        .then(displayResults)
}

function displayResults(weather) {
    console.log(weather)
    let city = document.querySelector('.cityy')
    city.innerHTML = `${weather.list[0].name}`
    let temp = document.querySelector('.current')
    temp.innerHTML = `${weather.list[0].main.temp}`
    let descr = document.querySelector('.description')
    descr.innerHTML = `${weather.list[0].weather[0].description}`
}
```

My button
`<input class="butt2" type="button" value="+"/>`

Comment: Is the button triggering the fetching of the data as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the weather response object to localStorage, you could modify your `getResults` function to:

```
function getResults(query) {
    fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=XXXXXX`)
        .then(weather => weather.json())
        .then(weather => {
          localStorage.setItem(weather.list[0].name, JSON.stringify(weather));
          return weather;
        })
        .then(displayResults)
}
```

Then, to retrieve the stored information you'd only have to call `localStorage.getItem` and parse it back to an object, like so:

```
displayResults(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name of city')));
```

#### Update

The first response would store the whole response of the API as an object. To store only what is displayed in the page when the user clicks the save button, you could do the following:

```
document.querySelector('.butt2').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const store = {
    city: document.querySelector('.city').innerHTML,
    temp: document.querySelector('.current').innerHTML,
    description: document.querySelector('.description').innerHTML
  };
  localStorage.setItem('saved-by-user', JSON.stringify(store))
});
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot, but now it saves when I simply press enter... meaning all cities will get stored. For the button to make the trick I assume have to do eventListener?

Comment: Yes, I believe there might be something more to it, you'd only like to store what is displayed in the page once the user clicks the button, right? Could you add the response from the API so that I can get a better idea of what data you are working with?

Comment: @learnjspsde I updated it to save only the displayed information, and overwrite it each time.

Comment: amazing, that's great and works perfectly. Lastly if not to overwrite? Cheers!

Comment: if you don't want to overwrite, you just have to change the first parameter of the `localStorage.setItem` function, so that instead of the string `'saved-by-user'` the key has a unique value. You could use the name of the city (though I don't know for sure if that is enough to guarantee uniqueness) like so: `localStorage.setItem(store.city, JSON.stringify(store))`